# lua language - attempt to call global

Tags: lua, lua-table

i have 2 array classMate and winners,  in need to check if winners in classMate, if yes put res[i] = 1

```
function win(classMates , winners)
    res = {}
    for i=1,#winners do
        for j=1,#classMates do
        print(3)
            if winners[i] == classMates[j] then res[i] = 1 else res[i] = 0 end
            print(res)
        end
    end

end
classMates = {"frank" , "alex" , "soli"}
winners = {"lora" , "frank" , "sandra" ,"alex"}
print(winners(classMates,winners))
```

but when i do that there is an error that said :
i use REPL for lua

```
lua: [string "<eval>"]:15: attempt to call global 'winners' (a table value)
```

stack traceback:
[string ""]:15: in main chunk

any help ?

Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
-- not print(winners)
-- cause winners is a table
-- instead
win({"frank" , "alex" , "soli"}, {"lora" , "frank" , "sandra" ,"alex"})
-- because win() does the print()
-- ...as i can see
```

end

> And also try in win() `print(res[i])` the foregoing print(3) should be `print(classMates[j])`